# JSfiddle results not appearing

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Why doesnt console.log('hello'); output anything in JSfiddle. I only ask because it tells me not to use document.write();  I dont know what else to use to output my data. Does anyone know the correct way to output data?

Comment: Where do you expect the text to appear? It's written on the [JavaScript console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners), not anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use alert, or you can insert the info into html on the page

Edit: Sorry misread the question, but those are still valid ways of seeing the data...

Answer (score 1):

Console writes to the literal browser console. In chrome hit tools > Javascript Console

Similar steps in Firefox and IE

EDIT:

Also, I know this is probably bad practice, but I do get lazy with looking at console all the time, so I usually end up creating a debug div and appending text to it.. /shameless